# Hangman project with Ruby. The letter 'm' is being registered as already inputted by the user if a different letter is inputted first

Tags: ruby

```
class Game
  def initialize
    @word = key_generator
    @guesses = 10
    @guess = ''
    @word_clues = ''
    @winner = false
    @word.length.times { |_l| @word_clues << '_' }
    @lettersleft = 0
  end

  def guess_checker(get_guess)
    return unless get_guess == 'exit'

    puts "\nBye Bye :)\n".red
    exit(true)
  end

  def enter_guess
    p @word

    puts "Enter a single letter guess\n"
    get_guess = gets.chomp.downcase
    raise "You've already guessed that letter!" if @guess.include? get_guess
    unless /[[:alpha:]]/.match(get_guess) && get_guess.length == 1 || get_guess == 'exit'
      raise "Invalid input: #{get_guess}. Try again!"
    end

    guess_checker(get_guess)
    guessed_letters(get_guess)
    display_guesses(get_guess)
    lettercount(get_guess)
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts e.to_s.red
  end

  def guessed_letters(char)
    if @word.include?(char)
      @guess << char.cyan
      puts "\nNice one! #{@guesses.to_s.cyan} guesses left."
    else
      @guess << char.red
      @guesses -= 1
      puts "\nNot so lucky, sorry! #{@guesses.to_s.cyan} guesses left.\n"
    end
  end

  def key_generator
    word_list = File.open('words_no_swears.txt')
    words = []

    word_list.each_line do |l|
      l = l.chomp
      words << l if l.length <= 12 && l.length >= 5
    end

    word_list.close
    words.sample
  end

  def winner_check
    return unless @word == @word_clues

    @winner = true
  end

  def game_play
    if @guesses >= 2 && @winner == false
      enter_guess
      puts
      puts "   Guesses: #{@guess}"
      puts
    elsif @guesses == 1 && @winner == false
      puts "\nLast guess!\n".cyan
      enter_guess
      display_guesses(@guess)
    else
      win_anouncement = "\nYou got it!\n"
      puts win_anouncement.cyan
      exit
    end
  end

  def go_time
    until @guesses == 0
      winner_check
      game_play
      puts @lettersleft
    end
    return unless @guesses == 0 && @winner == false

    puts "\n  Tough luck,\n  The word was #{@word.cyan}\n  Play again? [y/n]"
    entry = gets.chomp
    return unless entry == 'y'

    restart
    go_time
  end

  def restart
    @word = key_generator
    @guesses = 10
    @guess = ''
    @word_clues = ''
    @winner = false
    @word.length.times { |_l| @word_clues << '_' }
  end

  def display_guesses(char)
    @word.split('').each_with_index do |v, i|
      @word_clues[i] = char if v == char
    end
    puts
    puts '  ' + @word_clues.magenta
  end

  def lettercount(char)
    @word.split('').each do |v|
      @lettersleft += 1 if char == v
    end
    puts "letters to go: #{(@word.length - @lettersleft).to_s.cyan}"
  end
end
```

here is pretty much the entire code. I wasn't sure which specific parts would be relevant because I have no idea where the issue is being raise. This is a relatively rough draft, i know. Thank you so much for your help.

I have tried using various puts in places and scanning the code for issues. I have not found any. I have tried running the program in replit and bash with the same results.
The program asks the user for a single letter input, checks that the letter has not been guessed already. However, when the user's first guess is not the letter 'm' the check for the repetitive letter seems to think the letter 'm' is guessed.

Comment: `char.red` and `char.cyan` likely contain the letter 'm' as part of their control sequence. You shouldn't be using the same variable for outputting formatted data and for keeping track of internal data.

Comment: Once you have your program working you should consider posting it at SO's sister-site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There you will get valuable advice on how to improve your code. (Only working code can be posted there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Some General Notes

First of all, there are a number of issues with your code, and this isn't the right place for a code review. If you can't unit-test your methods, and you haven't [stepped through your code with a debugger](https://github.com/ruby/debug), it's hard to offer a solution that isn't one of many other perfectly valid solutions.

That said, you have a number of issues to address:

1. Never raise an exception for an expected behavior. Exceptions are for *exceptions*, not for flow control. So, please stop doing that.
2. You're doing a lot of work around getting a single character. Use something like:

   ```
   require "io/console"
   char = $stdin.getch
   ```

   instead. It makes your intention clearer and the code more readable.
3. Without spending a lot of time debugging your code, I'd recommend that you add something like:

   ```
   @unguessed_letters = ("a".."z").to_a
   ```

   to your class instance variables, and then remove the guessed character from the array after checking whether or not it's present. That seems much simpler and less error-prone than what you're currently doing.

This may improve your code, but won't necessarily fix what's wrong. Your code is just hard to read and debug as currently written, and simplifying non-working code is a great way to find a root cause.

### Example of a Character-Based Input Loop

Secondly, your code could benefit from a simple loop to test characters against both previously-guessed characters and the word the user is trying to complete. Avoid more complex parsing of input than you actually need; as the Agile Manifesto says, optimize the amount of "work not done." As an example, consider the following code, which assumes you've written #completed? and #reveal_letter methods. Note that in this example you delete the guessed letter either way *after* doing whatever you want with it.

```
require "io/console"

@guesses_remaining = 10
@unguessed_letters = ("a".."z").to_a

# This is an example, and depends on some methods
# you haven't written yet, like a Boolean result
# from #completed? and action for #reveal_letter.
#
# @todo You also need to handle CTRL-C and CTRL-D
#   if you want to exit to loop before you run out
#   of guesses. See Signal#trap and Signal#list,
#   but you'll have to handle CTRL-D explicitly if
#   you decide to allow EOF as way for the user to
#   exit the loop.
# @return [String, nil] @word if entire word was
#   revealed; otherwise nil when the loop runs
#   out of remaining guesses
while @guesses_remaining.nonzero?
  @guess = $stdin.getch
  next if @guess.match? /$/

  if @unguessed_letters.include? @guess
    reveal_letter(@guess) if @word.include?(@guess)
  else
    # assumes you only lose a remaining guess
    # if you've guessed wrong; modify if you
    # use different rules
    @guesses_remaining -= 1
  end

  @unguessed_letters.delete @guess
  break @word if completed?(@word)
end
```

This is not meant to be an exhaustive rewrite of your code, nor a debug of your existing code. It's just a pragmatic alternative that will handle a character at a time, and using a simplistic loop to manage guesses and accidentally pressing <kbd>RETURN</kbd> without selecting a letter.

It should be enough to get you started in a better direction, but is neither complete nor fully idiomatic. It just attempts to make your code easier to reason about and debug. The rest is up to you.